# install node js error in "make" command: "recipe for target 'node' failed"

Tags: node.js, cordova, makefile, make-install

I'm trying to install node js on my linux. I installed all the prerequisites correctly.
and I run ./configure correctly.
the problem is in "make" command and "make install" command

> make
>
> make install

-

here is what I received in the terminal after "make" command:

```
/usr/bin/python tools/gyp_node.py -f make
make -C out BUILDTYPE=Release V=1
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/islamassi/programming files/phoneGap/node-     v0.10.30/node/out'
Makefile:271: *** mixed implicit and normal rules.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/islamassi/programming files/phoneGap/node-   v0.10.30/node/out'
Makefile:45: recipe for target 'node' failed
make: *** [node] Error 2
```

-

and this after "make install" command:

```
make -C out BUILDTYPE=Release V=1
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/islamassi/programming files/phoneGap/node-v0.10.30/node/out'
Makefile:271: *** mixed implicit and normal rules.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/islamassi/programming files/phoneGap/node-   v0.10.30/node/out'
Makefile:45: recipe for target 'node' failed
make: *** [node] Error 2
```

Comment: Looks like the makefile generated here is invalid.  It's possible that it's falling afoul of https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?33034 in which case you should report this to the node js developers.  If you provided the actual content of line 271 of `out/Makefile`, as referenced in the error message, we could be sure.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get around this error by by :

```
./configure --without-snapshot
```

before the

```
make & make install
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error so I installed g++ that seemed to fix the issue for me.

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Then just run:

```
make
```

again.. and then:

```
sudo make install
```

Then you can check if node is installed with:

```
node -v
```

and you should see the version of node your running.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I ran those commands in external storage. Move them to your home and follow commands.

Answer (score 0):

You are maybe missing one or more of the compilation dependencies

```
sudo zypper install make gcc gcc-c++ glibc-devel
```